# How to get pgrep to display full process info

Tags: linux, bash, process, grep

Is there any way to get `pgrep` to give me all the info about each process that `ps` does?  I know I can pipe `ps` through `grep` but that's a lot of typing and it also gives me the `grep` process itself which I don't want.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`pgrep`'s output options are pretty limited. You will almost certainly need to send it back through `ps` to get the important information out. You could automate this by using a bash function in your `~/.bashrc`.

```
function ppgrep() { pgrep "$@" | xargs --no-run-if-empty ps fp; }
```

Then call the command with.

```
ppgrep <pattern>
```

Comment: Thanks!  I modified it to: `function ppgrep() { pgrep "$@" | xargs ps fp 2> /dev/null; }`  Otherwise, if no processes match your search, it dumps a whole `ps` usage megilla.

Comment: On OS X, the `ps` needs a hyphen for the flags: `function ppgrep() { pgrep "$@" | xargs ps -fp 2> /dev/null; }`

Comment: If you want to avoid the ps usage page, GNU xargs has an option, `-r` that will only execute the command if it has received a list.

Comment: More concise way is `ps fp $(pgrep -d, "$@")`

Answer (score 21):

**Combine `pgrep` with `ps` using `xargs`!**

```
pgrep <your pgrep-criteria> | xargs ps <your ps options> -p
```

For example try

```
pgrep -u user | xargs ps -f -p
```

to get a full process list of `user`. Option `-u user` limits `pgrep` to the user given (as a number or name) while the `ps` options `-f -p` request a full format listing for the selected PID.

It's nice that you keep the first line with the column names. `grep` always drops the column names.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, because it uses unix pipes in a proper way, taking a list of PIDs from one tool and feeding back into another (if it seems like hackery, it's not - this technique can be used in LOTS of UNIX tools, like email grep tools. The Bash function ppgrep() is an unnecessary dependency, and avoids confronting the learning opportunity presented here.)

Comment: @ScottPrive but, the OP said "I know I can pipe ps through grep but that's a lot of typing" so probably that is the reason why this is not the accepted answer.

Comment: @alerio-bozzolan Yes, the OP said "grep", and `"pgrep"` is a different application,  different installer package, different authors. pgrep is less typing, because it is specialized to only work with processes (it's not general-purpose like grep).

Answer (score 16):

*The following only gives you PID + full command-line.  For "all the info `ps` does", see other answers...*

Most linuxes use [procps-ng](https://gitorious.org/procps/procps).  Since 3.3.4 (released in 2012), **`pgrep -a`** (`--list-full`) shows the full command line.
Note: By default pgrep only matches the pattern you give against the executable name.
If you want to match against the full command line (as grepping ps does), add the `-f` (`--full`) option.

In older versions (including the original [procps](http://procps.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/procps/procps/pgrep.c?revision=1.30&view=markup#l471) project), `-l` option showed info but it's behavior varied:

- `pgrep -fl` matched the pattern against full command line and showed the full command line.
- `pgrep -l` alone matched only executable name and showed only executable name.
  If you don't want full match, you couldn't see the full command line :-(
  [https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=526355#15]

Not sure what code *BSD use but their [man page](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pgrep&sektion=1) documents the old `-fl` behavior.

Unfortunately you can't even use `-fl` portably - in recent procps-ng, `-f` (`--list-name`) always prints only the executable name.

Answer (score 12):

## Linux grep

For the GNU version of `pgrep` long + fuzzy output is achieved with `-af` and the string must be case-sensitive (i.e. *there is no option for case-insensitivity*).

```
$ pgrep -af apache

OUTPUT:
    1748 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

[Man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/pgrep.1.html):

```
   -a, --list-full
       List  the  full  command line as well as the process ID.  (pgrep only.)

   -f, --full
       The pattern is normally only matched against the process name.  
       When -f is set, the full command  line is used.
```

## MacOS/BSD grep

On MacOS/BSD `-l` (*long output*) in combination with `-f` (*match against full argument lists*) will display the complete command (`-i` adds case-insensitivity):

```bash
$ /usr/bin/pgrep -fil ssh

OUTPUT:
    33770 ssh: abc@192.168.0.123-22 [mux] t
```

[man page](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pgrep.1.html):

```bash
 -l          Long output.  For pgrep, print the
             process name in addition to the
             process ID for each matching
             process.  If used in conjunction
             with -f, print the process ID and
             the full argument list for each
             matching process.  For pkill, dis-
             play the kill command used for
             each process killed.
```

> ❗️NOTE: GNU `grep` can be installed on MacOS with `brew install pgrep` — this will expose the GNU flavour under `/usr/local/bin/pgrep` and depending on your **$PATH** config might break code which relies on the BSD syntax of `pgrep`.

Answer (score 2):

Use the -v option to grep - it returns everything BUT the requested pattern.

```
ps -ef | grep <process> | grep -v grep
```

Comment: This was the best answer for me. It shows you the full command without being truncated as it happens with `pgrep -u user | xargs ps -f -p`

Answer (score 1):

I know it is an old topic. However, It was useful to me, and I would like to share what I did that worked. It is pretty straightforward for beginner (like me) and may help others:

```
[root@2a8ad900f55e tmp]# pgrep -f '(^|/)db2fmcd'|xargs ps |awk '{print $5}'
COMMAND
/opt/ibm/db2/V11.5/bin/db2fmcd
```

Note that the column "CMD" was also showed, but the question of this thread was to show the command, and not only the command. Anyway, I am trying to remove that column and will update my post with the command too.

**Note:
The arguments "--no-headers and -o command" isolated the output only to the command. And I could remove the awk print.**

```
[root@2a8ad900f55e tmp]# pgrep -f '(^|/)db2fmcd'|xargs ps -o command --no-headers
/opt/ibm/db2/V11.5/bin/db2fmcd
[root@2a8ad900f55e tmp]#
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is, the most information you can get is the name and process id by using the -l option to pgrep.

ps supports all sorts of formatting options, so I would just make an alias for what you want to save the typing.  A simple way to exclude the grep process from the output us to include an additional pipe to `grep -v grep` to exclude any grep processes.

Answer (score 0):

In order to eliminate the `grep` process, you can use brackets as part of your pattern:

```
ps -ef | grep '[t]ty'
```

You can do this with `ps` and `pgrep`:

```
ps -fp $(pgrep -d, tty)
```

Answer (score -1):

This will help you I guess:

ps auxww

Comment: Can you please elaborate.  More info would improve this answer